# Install a light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

From my ceiling I have 2 black wires connected together, 2 white wires connected together, 1 red wire and 1 ground wire. How do I connect my light fixture to it?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both the ceiling box and the switch box please?

Comment: Was the house built after 2010?

Comment: Yes the house was built 4 years ago.

Comment: You connect the new fixture the same way the old one was connected...

Answer (score 3):

99% if wired normally for the age given:

Fixture green or bare to ground.

Fixture white to whites.

Fixture black to red.